# Bounty page not found?

Tags: bug, bounties, profile-page

I reloaded my bounties offered page and I got "Page not found"

But when I navigate to my offered bounties from my profile page it works fine (as soon as I press F5, it becomes not found again)

page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=bounties&sort=offered

---

The same goes for any of the bounty pages ending in `&sort=<x>`

Comment: That page has a contact-us link. Did you get any response when you tried it?

Comment: Yep. Thanks @TimStone